# Find and replace "[" and,or "]" using regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm searching domains from emails inside texts, email's "format" is like: [mailto:name@domain.com] and I'm finding them using this basic regular expression:

```
 $r = '/mailto:.*\]/';
```

then I'm aplying this:

```
substr(strrchr($matches[1][0], "@"), 1);
```

and final result is something like

domain.com]

So the question is, how to get rid of "]" or a better way to get only a domain from an email inside [mailto:name@domain.com] any sugestion? Thanks in advance!

Thanks!

Comment: `$r = '/mailto:[^]]*/';`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try lookahead in the regex:

```
$r = '/mailto:.*(?=\])/';
```

or just remove it from the result using `trim`:

```
$final = substr(strrchr($matches[1][0], "@"),1).trim("]");
```

And btw, you can just use lookbehind, so you don't need to use the `substr`:

```
$r = '/(?<=\[mailto:[^@]*@).*(?=\])/';
```

Comment: I've chose first option, and it worked perfectly, I must learn about trim, THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Change your expression to this.

```
$r = '/mailto:[^@]+@[^]]+/';
```

You can do this without using `substr` and a basic regular expression.

```
preg_match_all('/\[mailto:[^@]+@([^@]+)\]/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

See [working demo](https://eval.in/54728)

Answer (score 1):

Use rtrim

```
  'domain.com]'.rtrim("]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just try to extract the possible elements from the string:

`([\\w-+]+(?:\\.[\\w-+]+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,7})`